# Comparing function output with number. Disappearing result

Tags: function, shell, compare, output, minikube

**I'm trying to compare this** and a result is always false whether there is a process or not

```
 output=$(minikube ssh 'ps -ef | grep dashboard | grep -v grep | wc -l')
 if [[ "$output" == 0 ]]; then
   echo "Starting minikube dashboard"
 else
   echo "Minikube dashboard already has been started"
 fi
```

**Interesting moment**:

```
$echo $output
1
$echo "$output smth"
 smth
```

**So what is going on with a function output?**

Comment: Try this: `od -c <<<"$output"` -- I bet it ends with a `\r` character

Comment: thnks, you are rigth